# How to download file and store it in a folder using PowerShell in SharePoint?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

The objective is to download the latest excel file from SharePoint and save it in a local folder. The SharePoint doesn't have a specific filename, but we need to download only the latest one, and save it to the destination folder. I was able to get the latest file from SharePoint, but stuck in writing the file to local disk. Help is appreciated.

PS script to get the latest filename from SharePoint

```
$dir = "UNC Sharepoint folder"
$destinationfolder   = "C:\SharePoint\"
$filter="*.xlsx"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name
$fl=$latest.Name
$fl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Copy-Item (Join-Path $dir $fl) -Destination ($destinationfolder)
```

[Edit]: Less lines -

```
$dir = "UNC Sharepoint folder"
$destinationfolder   = "C:\sharepoint\"
$filter="*.xlsx"
Copy-Item (Join-Path $dir (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)) -Destination ($destinationfolder)
```